# Edgy Scrolling on UITableView - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm making an application that populates the table view from a parse database. The problem is there's a bit of lag whenever I scroll. Through some searching, I've come to realize that the problem lies in the cellForRowAtIndexPath() function where I'm querying the database in order to get the data I need for that cell's labels. I have to query the database there because I use the cell's position to index into my messages array in order to grab the right message. Here's the meat of my cellForRowAtIndexPath() function:

```
    if (path.row < messagesArray.count) {
        var message = messagesArray[path.row]
        var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
        query.whereKey("messageID", equalTo: message.messageID)
        var first = query.getFirstObject()

        if (message.senderID == loggedInUserID) {
            cell.nameLabel?.text = "I said"
        } else {
            queryO?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: message.senderID)
            var second = queryO?.getFirstObject()
            var name = second!.objectForKey("FIRST") as! String
            var middle = second!.objectForKey("MIDDLE") as! String?
            var last = second!.objectForKey("LAST") as! String

             if (middle != nil) {
                 cell.nameLabel?.text = name + " " + middle! + " " + last
              } else {
                  cell.nameLabel?.text = name + " " + last
              }
        }

        cell.messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        cell.messageLabel?.text = message.messageText

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mm a" // superset of OP's format
        let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(first!.objectForKey("TIME") as! NSDate)

        cell.senderLabel?.text = str
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the reason to making a query to Parse? You have the messages list already. It's bad idea to query even a local db, but networking is really a show stopper. Try Network Conditioner to fell your app on a mobile network.

Comment: You should pre-fetch all of the message data from Parse - or at least a reasonable subset, fetching more as you scroll down if needed

Comment: I agree with std.denis, and I notice that there is even a second parse query (?), query0. These queries are synchronous and take a lot of time. You should execute these queries outside this method, and do them async. You should store the results locally and use the local storage in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was I took the query outside my function and ran it in my viewDidLoad() which improved the speed drastically. Thanks for your help guys :-)